# Image with anchor tag XML and XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I need to create an image wrapped in an anchor tag with xml and xslt that will be displayed in an iframe

My XML looks like

```
<cars>
  <car>
    <name>Ferrari</name>
    <image>http://www.bestdrives.org/ferrari-cars/ferrari-fiorano.jpg</image>
    <link>http://www.ferrari.com/English/Pages/home.aspx</link>
  </car>
</cars>
```

I need the name and image to be wrapped in a anchor tag

my xslt looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<!-- Edited by XMLSpy® -->
<html xsl:version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <body>
    <xsl:for-each select="cars/car">
      <xsl:template match="car">
        <xsl:attribute name="href" select="link"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="name"/>
        <img>
  </html>              <xsl:attribute name="src" select="image"/>
        </img>
      </xsl:template>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </body>
```

Comment: Can you actually show the HTML you using for your IFrame? In particular, how are you actually applying the XSLT to your XML?

Comment: Just be referencing the XSLT file in the XML file? If i go to the XSLT then i can see the style (obviously without the content) but if i open the XML file or reference it through the iframe its just raw XML.

Answer (score 0):

something like this?
xslt:

```
    <xsl:template match="car">
        <a>
            <xsl:attribute name="href" select="link"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="name"/>
            <img>
                <xsl:attribute name="src" select="image"/>
            </img>
        </a>
    </xsl:template>
```

Comment: That doesnt work for me it just pulls out the unstyled xml is my page layout correct ill update the original questions

Answer (score 0):

The XSLT you've supplied is not well-formed XML (the closing `</html>` tag has ended up inside the `<img>` element for some reason, and the `<?xml` declaration must be the *very first* thing in the file with no leading whitespace in front of it).  It also isn't valid XSLT - you can't put a `template` inside a `for-each`, and you can't use `select` on `<xsl:attribute>` in XSLT 1.0 (though you can in XSLT 2.0).  How about this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<html xsl:version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <body>
    <xsl:for-each select="cars/car">
      <a href="{link}">
        <xsl:value-of select="name"/>
        <img src="{image}" />
      </a>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </body>
</html>
```

The `href="{link}"` notation is called an [attribute value template](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#attribute-value-templates), and it's a less verbose version of `<xsl:attribute name="href"><xsl:value-of select="link" /></xsl:attribute>`

Comment: Nope the xml still comes into the iframe unstyled

Comment: @StephenRomero how are you referencing the XSLT from the XML?  Are you using an `<?xml-stylesheet?>` processing instruction and expecting the browser to do the styling or are you using a server-side technology to do the transform (and if so which one)?